# How to set Shadow on Bottom for UIView control + iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, shadow, dropshadow

Before asking this question, I found so many answers at stack overflow but none worked for my case.

Requirement:
[image]

I tried:

```
private func setShadow() {
    contentView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    contentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.5)
    contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 0.5
    contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
}
```

I also play around with offset, radius, opacity; studied about each property, but none combination results in desired output. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Is `contentView` the white rectangle? And you're trying to get the shadow you are showing in your image? What do you see if you set `.shadowRadius = 5`? Or set shadow color to black?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the effect by static layer.

```
contentView.layer.masksToBounds = false

let shadowLayer = CALayer()
shadowLayer.frame = contentView.bounds
shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.5);
shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 0.5
shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
contentView.layer.addSublayer(shadowLayer)
```

Please remember to input it in `layoutSubviews` if you use autolayout .

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    shadowLayer.frame = contentView.bounds
}
```

Comment: cell is reusable and layoutSubviews may be called mutliple times

Comment: @Gargo I adjust the code a bit, just change frame in `layoutSubviews`